# CC2541 (HM10) HID and programming

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, hid, ftdi, hm-10

AIM: use the processor and bluetooth purely on the cc2541 to read from the free pins on the board but outputting in HID format so it could be used as a keyboard.

I understand that there are a few offical TI hardware components that usually are used to program it (I cannot afford the development kit). Would someone please help me either using arduino and a FTDI board program the cc2541 to do this?

Answer (score 1):

While I have no idea how to use the CC2541, if you're limited by a budget you could get a HC-05 for 4 dollars-ish, and if you so happen to have a (old) PC with a parallel port you can reflash it using RN-42 firmware (need to solder 6 wires and plug em into that port with some resistors), which will allow it do become HID devices like joysticks,keyboards and mice.

Comment: I would use the HC-05 which I already have but I don't have an old desktop with a parallel port. I already tried doing that but I have a laptop. That's why I got the cc2541 so I could possibly get that to work on BLE. I already flashed it with official HM-10 software.

Comment: If that doesn't work out you could buy a bluesmirf(40$) , but those are ridiculously expensive, if you consider they're essentially hc-05's with rn-42 firmware

Comment: Thanks but I ended up buying a ccdebugger :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumble on this post later on, the following could help a lot I guess ;)

[flashing an HC-05 with another firmware using an FTDI adapter](http://forum.espruino.com/comments/14444935/)

Enjoy ;)
+